# SharePoint 2007 merge nested document library items

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

is it possible to collect (i.e. merge, consolidate, de-normalize, etc.) items from multiple nested document libraries on a site?  My manager wants to flatten our MOSS 07 site's current nested hierarchical directory list structure and combine all items into a single, flat document library repository.

Anyway, I've been considering how this can be accomplished using, for example, the SPServices Javascript library, but I'm not sure if JS is the best approach  for this kind of task.  I also have Sharepoint Designer 2007 and VS 2010 dev tools at my disposal.  From what I understand VS 2010 is not fully backward compatible with MOSS 2007 (please correct if I'm wrong), so it seems I basically just have SharePoint Designer 07 to work with along with MOSS 07's out-of-box tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can created CrossList dataview web parts, content query web parts, or custom web parts created in Visual Studio to consolidate the data.

The more straightforward approach would be to just use Content and Structure or Open in Windows Explorer to move files into a central document library. No development overhead, the only downside is if anyone had RSS feeds/bookmarks/Connect to Outlook those links would be broken.

Comment: Thanks PirateEric, I was able to move files using the Windows Explorer perspective.  I like the idea of a CrossList DVWP, can a cross-site or content query web part collect items from nested document libraries?  My supervisors are leaning toward getting rid of nested directories completely, so we may end up just moving items manually using Windows Explorer as you suggested.  Be nice if there was a way to automate that process...

Comment: They should be able to do recursive folder searching yes.

Comment: Thanks again PirateEric, I'll accept you suggestions as an answer and present these options to my team.  So it seems we can either create a view of site-wide items using the CrossList DVWP or CQWP.  Or move the files out physically through the Windows Explorer view.

Comment: I'd be moreso in favor of merging them into a singular library. This will allow you to apply metadata as needed and then use the default Sharepoint UI to create views as needed.